# Why does this not work? I am trying to write a small program that prompts a user to enter any double value

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

So i have to prompt a user to enter any double value then if it is not a double value i am supposed
to flush the buffer then prompt the user for another value, then print the value if it is a double.

```
    double value;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter any double value: ");
    value = sc.nextDouble();

    while (!sc.hasNextDouble())
        {
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter a valid value: ");
            value = sc.nextDouble();

        }
    System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Might want to add exactly what you get when you run it vs what you expect (as well as the input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of the loop,

```
// value = sc.nextDouble();
while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) // <-- while we don't have a double
    {
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a valid value: ");
        // value = sc.nextDouble();
    }
value = sc.nextDouble(); // <-- here
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott that helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a do while loop to save having to get input in two places in code. Then, make sure you're assigning the value variable outside of the loop.

```
double value;
Scanner sc;

do{
    System.out.println("Enter any double value: ");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}while(!sc.hasNextDouble());

value = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println(value);
```